# Using require within a react component

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Say I have the following ReactJS component:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const jsonData = require("./theJsonData.json");

  return <ChildComponent jsonData={jsonData} />
}
```

Notice the `require()` call within the React component. Normally, I'd import the JSON using `import`, at the top of the file.

Will someone articulate to me WHY it is wrong to do this. I realize it's uncommon and I've never even seen this approach in the wild. But it does work. I'm looking for a well articulated explanation of WHY it's a bad approach.

Or, if you think it's a good approach, I'd love to learn that too.

UPDATE:
The question still stands, but I wanted to note a bit of research I just did. I just verified that all `requires` to this file, will reference the same object at run time. Each `require()` will be replaced by a call to `__webpack_require__('the/path.json')`. That call returns the same object, always. Even if you use it in different components.

So my initial concern of having 20 copies of the JSON data (20 objects for 20 components) is gone.

So now I really don't know what the issue is. Is there even an issue with this approach, or does it simply "look" wrong.

Comment: Why to allow an opportunity for performance issues? You already knows it can happen, how can you assure other developer won't use it as intended?

Comment: Between a solution that definitely has no problem (`import` at the beginning) and a solution that may introduce performance problem(`require`), which would you choose ?

Comment: I appreciate these two comments of "play it safe". I posted to the question so that an expert in webpack or requireJS could specify the exact issue that it causes (or if there even is one).

For instance, require uses __webpack_require__('path') at runtime to access the object (but is it a new one each time, or are they all references to the same object), whereas import replaces variable assignments with a global reference to the object that is prefixed with the name in underscores. I was hoping someone would explain the CONS of using require() from that perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I think an important benefit that es6 imports provide over 'require' is the ability to reduce Javascript payloads.

Unlike with require statements, named imports allow you to only use dependencies you are actually using in your application, and webpack can shed the dependencies that weren't explicitly imported in your production build.

Comment: It sounds like you're referring to cherry picking, but in this example, we're importing a JSON file. We're not using a named export. We're importing an entire JSON file.